# Reference to lvalue or rvalue for fundamental types or object

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I observe a different behavior for the compiler with the 2 following snippets of code:

With the first one, all seems OK to me with fundamental type like `int`:

```
void fi1(int& a) {}
void fi2(int&& a) {}

void func1() {
    fi1(2+2); // Do not compile: normal since '2+2' is temporary and is not a variable
    int a = 5;
    fi2(a); // Do not compile: normal since 'a' is an lvalue
}
```

But I do not understand the second one with object type:

```
void fs1(string& a) {}
void fs2(string&& a) {}

void func2() {
    fs1(string{""}); // Compile: but weird for me since there is no variable to reference !
    fs2(string{""}); // Compile: normal since 'string{""}' is temporary and is not a variable
}
```

In the following post:
[Understanding lvalue/rvalue expression vs object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319035/understanding-lvalue-rvalue-expression-vs-object-type)

it is explained that an lvalue is when you can take its address. For sure, `string{""}` shall have an address somewhere in memory. But for me a key-point with rvalue is that you can't use it afterwards, making 'move semantic' possible.

When you are in `fs2` function, the argument is an rvalue and you can do whatever you want without any side effect. In `fs1`, you expect that some variable elsewhere will have some impact if you modify it. `fs2` should only be called with variable argument.

And why is working as expected with `int` and not with object ?

Comment: If you understand why an rvalue can't be passed to `fi1`, why is it surprising that you can't pass one to `fs1`?

Comment: If you make a reference to a const, you will resolve may errors.

Comment: `fs1(string{""});` [doesn't compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G3Mq5G6o7). Well, MSVC does compile it, but it's wrong. It stops doing so if you pass `/std:c++latest`.

Comment: I suspect this question is about the notorious Microsoft Visual C++ extension that allows non-const references to bind to temporaries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat try MSVC, it has extensions that allow binding non-const refs to temporaries. EDIT I see you just have ;)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but I can pass the rvalue to fs1, it compiles and I have run the program. That is why I do not understand !

Comment: Unrelated to the question, inability to take addresses of rvalues is an artifical limitation. They do have addresses (xvalues at least, prvalues are not actual objects and don't have addresses). You can get those addresses using something like `int *foo(int &&x) {return &x;}`.

Comment: @Jean-LucDelarbre what compiler do you use?

Comment: Ok thank you all guys, I am reassured, my understanding of lvalue/rvalue is good. Effectively I use MSVC and It is just its behavior which is wrong !

Comment: Related (Duplicate?): [Non-const reference bound to temporary, Visual Studio bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380966/non-const-reference-bound-to-temporary-visual-studio-bug)

Comment: You can also compile with `/permissive-` to disable this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior is due to the usage of MSVC.